# Missing number, treated as zero & Color stack action is missing. & Undefined control sequence

Tags: color, numbering, undefined

> I have tried to solve these issues since last weekend.  I have a
> number of issues, as the title shows. Any suggestions.
>
> - Missing number, treated as zero.
> - Color stack action is missing
> - Undefined control sequence
> - no references

```
                 \listfiles
%\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}

%\documentclass[11pt,modernstyle]{thesis}
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
%\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{thesis} 
%\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\iffalse
\textwidth=6in \oddsidemargin=0.5in \topmargin=-0.5in
\textheight=9in  % 9in must include page numbers
\textfloatsep = 0.4in \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.4in} \hfill
    Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{0.2in} \hspace{0.13in} \
    Figure\hfill Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{0.2in}
    \hspace{0.13in} \ Table\hfill Page\endgraf}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/SIU850607993/Documents/Conferences/CLOUD-2017/fig/}}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy,bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{eepic}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{figure}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[subfigure, titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}


\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand{\nomname}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\makenomenclature
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG, .eps, .tiff}

\urlstyle{same}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    %\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{\today}
    
    \pagenumbering{alph}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}\enlargethispage{\the\footskip}%
        \begin{center}
            { {\textbf{CCCg}}\par }%
            \vskip.4in
            Author
            
            {Yousef Alsenani}
            \vskip .3in
            Supervisors
            
            {Dr. osby\\
                Dr. med\\
                Dr. sco}
            \vskip .3in
            
            \begin{doublespace}
                NDALE\\
                PH.D. RESEARCH PROPOSAL\\ [.1in]
            \end{doublespace}
            A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
            for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\\
            in the
            Department of Computer Science\\
            in the Graduate School\\
            Soale
        \end{center}
        %%%Uncomment for Signatures%%%
        
        %\\[.14in]
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%Uncomment  for Approved Names%%%%%%
        %\begin{center}
        %\begin{doublespace}
        %Approved:\\
        %Professor John D. Doe \\
        %Professor Jane D. Doe
        %\end{doublespace}
        %\end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    %\input{abstract}
    %\doublespacing
    \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{2}
    
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    
    
    %\listoftables
    \newpage
    %\listoffigures
    \newpage
    
    
    \normalsize
    %\doublespacing
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
    %------------------------------------------------SECTION------------------------------------------------%
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \title{Reteud}
    
    
    \section{Emerging Trends}
    XXXXXXx
    
    
    %\input{introduction}
    \iffalse
    \input{relatedwork}
    %\input{analysis}
    \input{architecture}
    %\input{algorithm}
    \input{evaluaiton}
    \input{conclusion}
    \input{introduction2}
    \input{relwork2}
    \input{analysis2}
    \input{architecture2}
    \input{conclusion2}
    \input{summary}
\fi 
    \begin{spacing}{0.88}
        \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
        \bibliography{cloud}
    \end{spacing}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you, I have updated it

Comment: `siugrad51` class is not a standard one and you do not link to it. I tried changing it to `article` but then your example runs without error. Can you demonstrate the error using a standard class?

Comment: You are right. I tried `article` class. So how to solve `siugrad51` one?

Comment: its an error in a file I don't have, don't make us search the internet for it, where did you get the file?

Comment: School format requirements

Comment: that does not help anyone else debug the file for you, if we are not at your school and you do not make the file available.  You have not even said which command is undefined.

Comment: Dear, I just want to make sure the code above is correct and the packages are fine. I provide a sample of one error.  if it gets solved, it means the other error will be solved. No need to share all files. It is the same error in the entire document

Comment: I only know what you already know, the code works with article class. You have not shown your class code nor shown the error messages so I can give you no information or help other than what you already know, sorry.